# CSS- Hover Effect not working on specific Element

Tags: css, hover

Im new at coding and I am attempting to put a hover effect on a background image. Im using Grids and the first one works fine but the 2nd one will not work. I have about 5 others following the 1st and I cant get them to work ethier. What am I missing here? Its the same exact code.

```
.blog1 {
margin-top:5%;
grid-column: 1 /  3;   
grid-row: 3 / 3;   
background-image: url(../../Images/EditedImages/OdellOutsideedited.png);
min-height: 300px;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: top; 
**transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;  
opacity: 1;
}
.blog1:first-child:hover {
opacity: 0.75;

}**


.blog2 {
margin-top: 5%;
grid-column:  3 / 5  ; 
grid-row: 3 /  3;
background-image: url(../../Images/EditedImages/2RandomDrinking.png);
min-height: 300px; 
background-size:cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
transition: all ease-in-out 300ms; 
opacity: 1;
}

.blog2:first-child:hover {
opacity: 0.75;

}



 HTML

<div class="grid">

<div class="blog1"></div>
<div class="blog2"></div>
<div class="blog3"></div>
<div class="blog4"></div>
<div class="blog5"></div>
<div class="blog6"></div>
```

Comment: remove first-child ... and share your HTML code so am sure about your error, as I aleady have a duplicate

Comment: remove first-child from the CSS, keep on the hover and it will work fine

Comment: Awesome thanks! My preview wasnt working before for some reason. I tried that a million times but as long as its working now. Thank you for your help and patience.